# Python AttributeError: module 'x.y' has no attribute 'z'

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I'm seeing some strange behavior with some python imports:

Here are the commands I run:

```
import x
x.y.z
> AttributeError: module 'x.y' has no attribute 'z'
from x.y import z
kola_core.utils.node_utils
> < No Error >
```

Why must I explicitly import 'z' from 'x.y'?

This is the file strucutre:

```
x
--__init__.py
--y
  --__init__.py
  --z.py
```

Comment: is z a module or a function inside the module ?

Comment: A module, I edited the post to show the file structure.

Comment: Z is a module inside package Y. 
so if you say import x.y.z it imports all the functionalities inside Z. 

but if you say from x.y import Z it looks for function Z inside y.py which isnt available.